# Perforce Server connection error in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, perforce, p4v

Good Day everyone!

I am trying to configure `perforce` server in `OS X(10.8.4)` . I tried to follow instructions from [here](http://www.perforce.com/documentation/tenminute-test-drive-mac). In fact i am not sure if i am doing it right ! Please check the commands below that i entered in Terminal.

```
Last login: Sun Sep  1 02:13:19 on ttys000
MDs-MacBook-Pro:~ Emon$ export PATH=~/perforce:$PATH export P4PORT=1666
MDs-MacBook-Pro:~ Emon$ cd ~/perforce chmod a+x p4d p4d -d
MDs-MacBook-Pro:perforce Emon$ chmod a+x p4
MDs-MacBook-Pro:perforce Emon$ mkdir ~/myws cd ~/myws p4 client myws
mkdir: /Users/Emon/myws: File exists
mkdir: p4: File exists
MDs-MacBook-Pro:perforce Emon$
```

After that i tried to connect from `p4v`, but the following occurs !

In connection setup assistance i tried (as instructed in the [link](http://www.perforce.com/documentation/tenminute-test-drive-mac))

```
Host : localhost
Port : 1666
```

And the connection continues to refuse showing this...

```
Connect to server failed;check $P4PORT.
TCP Connection to localhost:1666 failed.
Connect: 127.0.0.1:1666 : Connection refused.
```

Please someone guide me in this regard. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some formatting problems with that web page.   Try these commands instead:

Set up the path and port variables:

```
export PATH=~/perforce:$PATH 
export P4PORT=1666
```

Set executable bits on p4d and p4 and start p4d in its default configuration

```
cd ~/perforce
chmod a+x p4d 
p4d -d
chmod a+x p4
```

Create a test directory for your workspace and initialize the client

```
mkdir ~/myws 
cd ~/myws 
p4 client myws
```

I think they accidentally reformatted the page, so the line breaks were missing.